# Which wordpress theme framework should I use?

Tags: wordpress, frameworks, themes, wordpress-theming

I have decided to use framework to develop my own custom wordpress theme? But I'm confused which one to use?
Or should I continue to write all up codes myself. I use 960 as css framework and jQuery as js library.
Any help will be cordially appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I would vote for famous and feature-rich [Thesis Theme Framework](http://joshkotsay.com/wordpress/best-wordpress-themes).

[Thesis Home](http://diythemes.com/)

You can find out more through a poll conducted here:

- [Poll – Which WordPress Theme Framework To Use?](http://www.scratch99.com/2009/02/poll-wordpress-theme-frameworks/)

Comment: Actually I'm looking for something under GPL licence and community driven

Comment: Thanks for the poll link. I'll adopt Thematic.

Answer (score 1):

I always have used http://wpframework.com/. It is a beautiful framework, community driven, and lock tight. Without all the unnecessary bells and whistles of the costly packaged frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using the Thesis Theme Framework... but the company (DIY Themes) is having some problems and for now, the Thesis future is somewhat unknown, with some partners leaving the company, Pearson (the Thesis creator) with problems with Matt (The Wordpress creator), etc...

So for now, I wouldn't recommend Thesis. I'd go with the Genesis Framework or Headway. Headway is easy to configure with a visual editor which makes things very easy (Thesis is not as easy as it seems, though).

Comment: Actually I'm looking for something under GPL licence and community driven. I'll adopt Thematic.

Answer (score 0):

I used Thesis until recently when I switched to the Frugal. Thesis is good if you are at ease with codes.

Frugal is a no brainer and one can actually come up with a totally unique layout just by clicking the mouse. No need to learn any codes, just takes a little bit of time to get use to the maze of options available.